# How to set focus table row in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamic table created in javascript. when page is loaded, I want to set the focus to first row of table and highlight the focused row to indicate as cursor.

Now using arrow keys(Up and down) I want to navigate through each row of table.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should probably read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Needs solution in plain javascript please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DataTables you can use:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    oTable.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('focused');  
});


oTable.find('tbody tr').click(function() {
    oTable.find('tbody tr').removeClass('focused');
    $(this).addClass('focused');
});
```

CSS

```
tr {
    border:1px inset white;
}
tr.focused {
   border:1px solid red; 
}
```